# Creating Dropdown for a list in html

Tags: html

```
<ul class="treeview-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="issueList1.html">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> 
            <b> 
                <spring:message code="all.projects" text="All Projects" />
            </b>
        </a>
    </li>
    <c:forEach items="${userProjects}" var="ItwProjecttemp">
        <li>
            <a href="issueList1.html?projectId=${ItwProjecttemp.id}">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>${ItwProjecttemp.projectname}
            </a>
        </li>
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

I have used to above code for list view of my project. I want it in dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Try the select tag instead:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok, then post the CSS like vel said. Use JSFiddle if possible to show us.

Comment: <select   onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" >
 <option value="issueList1.html?projectId=${null}">All Projects</option>
 <c:forEach items="${userProjects}" var="ItwProjecttemp">
<option value="issueList1.html?projectId=${ItwProjecttemp.id}" > ${ItwProjecttemp.projectname}</option>
</c:forEach></select>
I am able to achieve dropdown by using above code but i am not able to display the selected text in dropdown. functionality wise it is working as expected.